# I am not able to pass two list object of array to the controller method parameter its showing one parameter another is not passing

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("#btnCreate").click(function () {

        prepareCheckedQuestion();

        questionCountOperation();

        var NoOfQuestion= $("#hideCountedQuestions").val();
        var SelectedQuestion = $("#hidSelectedQuestions").val();

    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckValidation1", "Dashboard")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: NoOfQuestion,SelectedQuestion,
            success: function `enter code here`(data) { alert('Success'); },
        error: function (data) { alert('Error'); }
        })`enter code here`
```

public JsonResult CheckValidation1(List

NoOfQuestion, List SelectedQuestion)

Comment: Here is my controller method :public JsonResult CheckValidation1(IEnumerable<PaperSetDifficultyModel> NoOfQuestion, IEnumerable<TeacherPaperSetQuestionsModel> SelectedQuestion)

Comment: `data: NoOfQuestion,SelectedQuestion,` is invalid.  `data` should be given a query string, or an Object of key values to turn into a query string, or a string containing json.  In this case, you are incorrectly trying to give it two variables.

Comment: you mean we should do var data=json.stringfy(object)

Comment: From your controller, it's not clear that you are expecting json for input.  It looks like you are expecting two named fields?

Comment: yes I wants to Json for input

Comment: When I am passing Only one parameter its done but two parameter is not taking

Comment: Then, yes, you need to `JSON.stringify(someVariable)` for the data, where `someVariable` is an object containing the key value pairs your controller expects.

Comment: Because `{ key: value, value }` is not valid object syntax.

Comment: But I also tried it in that case our method is not calling..

Comment: yes you were right. but for the list item we have to pass after array object.---